# Ends of a group and Spherical growth function

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, infinite-groups

I am trying to get some intuition about a spherical growth function of a group, using the notation from [A. Mann](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107657504) $s_G(m)=\sum_{n=0}^m a_G(n)$, where $s_G(m)$ is the cumulative growth function and $a_G(n)$ the strict growth function.

For example for $G=\mathbb{Z}$ with one generator, $a_G(n)=2$ for all $n$. And in general, I can not assume that $a_G(n)$ is not eventually constant, for example for free groups, $a_G(n)$ increases as long as $n$ does, but as I mentioned, in $\mathbb{Z}$ it doesn't. And my intuition tells me that if $G$ has one end or infinite ends, $a_G(n)$ has enough "space" to grow together with $n$. This is something like:

CLAIM: If $G$ is a group with one end or infinite ends, then $a_G(n)$ is not eventually constant. Does this make sense? I don't have any ideas trying to prove this statement. Or there are groups that have different behaviors?
Any intuition about this would be appreciated.

Edit: Maybe I need another hypothesis similar to: If $\Gamma$ is the Cayley Graph of $G$ with a finite group of generators, and it has the property that $\Gamma - B_n(u_0)$ is a connected graph where $B_n(u_0)$ is the ball with center $u_0$ and  $n\in \mathbb{N}$ for any vertex $u_0$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$??

Comment: It sounds like the growth function depends on the choice of generating set, right? I wonder if even $\mathbb{Z}$ might have a periodic, rather than constant, growth function if you choose a clever generating set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $a_G(n)$ is eventually constant, and that constant is not zero. Then the cumulative growth function has linear bounds above and below.

By [Gromov's polynomial growth theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%27s_theorem_on_groups_of_polynomial_growth), $G$ has a finite index nilpotent subgroup.

The [Bass-Guivarch theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%27s_theorem_on_groups_of_polynomial_growth#Growth_rates_of_nilpotent_groups) gives the exact degree of polynomial growth of a finitely generated nilpotent group, and in particular a nilpotent group that has a cumulative growth function with linear bounds above and below has a finite index subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$.

The group $G$ therefore has a finite index subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$, and so $G$ has two ends.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know any book or article where I can learn more about this Bass-Guivarch theorem? I am not so familiarized with central series and I would like to understand this better

Comment: In that link I gave, next to Bass' name there is a citation to his paper.